# How can I send data to Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a user authentication for my bookmarking extension. The extension works with the Google App Engine (Python) backend at http://ting-1.appspot.com/.

The first time the extension runs, `background.html` opens `options.html` in a new tab and the user enters his email address. I send the email address to the app like this (not tried yet):

```
in options.html
---------------

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("extension_user", userEmail);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/authsender", true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

In the app, the handler `AuthSender` sends the confirmation email to the user:

```
class AuthSender(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        new_user = self.request.get("extension_user") 
        mail.send_mail(
        sender="Ting <ting@gmail.com>",
        to=new_user,
        subject="Ting Bookmarking: confirm your email",
        body="""click on the link below to confirm your email: 
<a href="http://ting-1.appspot.com/authHandler"></a> 

Happy Bookmarking!""")
```

If the user clicks the link in the email `AuthReceive` handler in the app will process the request and send confirmation to the extension. But I could not figure out how to send the confirmation to the extension.

When the user clicks on the link, how can I send confirmation back to the extension? Do I use `XMLHttpRequest` again? How? And what kind of listener I need to put at the extension?

Below is a sketch of the `AuthReceive` handler in the app:

```
class AuthReceive(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):

#---------------------------------------
        #receive email // I know this part
        #send confirmation to extension // I need help with this
#--------------------------------------
...
```

And in background.html

```
//...
// add listener and save the variable to localStorage
//...
```

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

This is the code to conform to [Moishe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939633/how-can-i-send-data-to-chrome-extension/7941923#7941923). Everything works except the last step: `handler.onmessage` is not triggered.

**options.html**

```
<html>
<head><title>Extension Options</title></head>
<body>
<p>Enter your gmail address:</p>

<textarea id="getEmail" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 250px; height: 20px">
</textarea><br />

<button id="save">Save</button>
<!--<button id="save">Clear</button>-->

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("getEmail").placeholder = "your gmail address" ;

//send entered gmail address to the server
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener
(
    "click", 
    function ()
    {
        var userEmail = document.getElementById("getEmail").value;
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("extension_user", userEmail);

        var channel;
        var socket;
        var handler = new Object();
        handler.onmessage =
        function (evt)
        {   
            //evt.data will be what the server sends in channel.send_message
            console.log("evt.data received from authhandler: " + evt.data);
        };    

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onReadyStateChange = function()
        {
            //error handling etc not included
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            {
                token = xhr.responseText;
                channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
                socket = channel.open(handler);
            }
        };
        xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/authsender", true);
        xhr.send(formData);
        console.log("formData sent to authsender: " + formData);

    }, false
)
//...
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**AuthSender and AuthHandler**

```
class AuthSender(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        new_user = self.request.get("extension_user")
        link = "http://ting-1.appspot.com/authhandler?new_user=%s" % new_user

        message = mail.EmailMessage()
        message.sender="Ting <ting@gmail.com>"
        message.to=new_user
        message.subject="Ting Bookmarking - Confirm your email"
        message.body="""Click on the link to confirm your email: %s """ % link
        message.send()

        logging.info("message sent to: %s " % message.to)

        token = channel.create_channel(new_user)
        self.response.out.write(token)

class AuthHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        new_user = self.request.get("new_user")

        channel.send_message(new_user, new_user)

        logging.info("new_user sent to client: %s" % new_user)
```

---

---

**Working version**

([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961638/why-does-google-app-engine-channel-api-jsapi-fail-to-load-in-a-chrome-extensio))

**options.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Extension Options</title>
    <!-- this does not work because it is local url
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Enter your gmail address:</p>

<textarea id="getEmail" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 250px; height: 20px">
</textarea><br />

<button id="save">Save</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("getEmail").placeholder = "your gmail address" ;

document.getElementById("save").addEventListener
(
    "click", 
    function ()
    {
        var userEmail = document.getElementById("getEmail").value;
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("extension_user", userEmail);

        var channel;
        var socket;
        var handler = 
        {
            onopen: function () { alert("onopen") },
            onerror: function () { alert("onerror") },
            onclose: function () { alert("onclose") },
            onmessage: 
            function (evt)
            {
                alert("evt.data is: " + evt.data)
            }
        };    

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            {
                token = xhr.responseText;
                channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
                socket = channel.open(handler);
            }
        };
        xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/authsender", true);
        xhr.send(formData);            
    }, false
)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**AuthSender and AuthHandler**

```
class AuthSender(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        new_user = self.request.get("extension_user")
        link = "http://ting-1.appspot.com/authhandler?new_user=%s" % new_user

        message = mail.EmailMessage()
        message.sender="Ting <ting@gmail.com>"
        message.to=new_user
        message.subject="Ting Bookmarking - Confirm your email"
        message.body="""Click on the link to confirm your email: %s """ % link
        message.send()

        token = channel.create_channel(new_user)

        self.response.out.write(token)

class AuthHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        new_user = self.request.get("new_user")

        self.response.out.write(new_user)

        channel.send_message(new_user, new_user)
```

Comment: By "e-mail" do you perchance mean "e-mail *address?"*

Comment: @kindall; yes, thanks for clarifying. I propose to get the email address of the user in `AuthReceive` handler in the app, like `userEmail = message.sender` and send this information to the extension. I am trying to find out how to send `userEmail` to the extension. Thanks again.

Comment: You persist in trying to cook up your own authentication solution. What is wrong with Chrome-to-Phone's?

Comment: @Nick Johnson, I am sure there is nothing wrong with Chrome-to-Phone authentication solution. But there are several reasons why I am unable to use it: 1. I cannot even figure out which source file to read. 2. In the files that I tried to read I could not separate what is related to auth from the rest of the code so that I can try to use it 3. I don't understand why I need to use OAuth when I am not trying to access any private data of the user 4. I cannot figure out which is the consumer and which is the service provider in my case. Thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: @Zeynel 1. [this](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/trunk/appengine/src/com/google/android/chrometophone/server/AuthServlet.java) would be a good place to start. 2. Then ask specific questions about how to understand the code! 3. Because you are accessing private data of the user - you're storing and retrieving bookmarks. That should use authentication. 4. Your extension is the consumer.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Thanks for the comment. That was not one of the files that I was looking at. I am using Python so it will take me some time to figure out what this java code does. I was wondering if you could sketch it in few words so that at least I have some anchor points to decipher the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html) to accomplish this. Request a token at the same time you make the XMLHttpRequest, and open the channel to listen for messages. When your app processes the HTTP request corresponding to the user clicking on the link, send a message to the channel that was created for that user's extension.

More detail:

Basically, in options.html when you make the XHR, do something like this:

```
var channel;
var socket;
var handler = {
  onmessage: function(evt) {
    // evt.data will be what your server sends in channel.send_message
  }
};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onReadyStateChange = function() {
  // error handling and whatnot elided
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 and xhr.status == 200) {
    // We got a response from the server. The responseText is
    // a channel token so we can listen for a "verified" message.
    token = xhr.responseText;
    channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
    socket = channel.open(handler);
  }
};
xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/authsender", true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Then on your server, the handler for the 'authsender' page will do something like this:

```
class AuthSenderHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    # get whatever data is in the form to send an email.
    # let's say that user_id is a field we extracted either from a cookie or from
    # the POST parameters themselves.
    link = "http://your.server.com/authHandler?user_id=%s" % user_id
    message = mail.EmailMessage()
    message.body = """some stuff %s""" % link
    # fill in other message fields, then send it.

    # now we'll create a channel token using the user_id and return 
    # it to the client.
    token = channel.create_channel(user_id)
    self.response.out.write(token)
```

The above two functions will get your client listening on a channel. The next step is: what happens when the user clicks a link?

Before, we sent the link in an email including a user_id parameter (for purposes of illustration; you may want to use something else). Now when the user clicks on the link, it'll make an HTTP request to the `authHandler` path with `user_id` as a parameter. So we can use the user_id to identify the channel to send a message to, like so:

```
class AuthHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    user_id = self.request.get("user_id")
    # send a message indicating the user received the email and
    # verified to our client page. You may want to send other data.
    channel.send_message(user_id, "authorized")
    # probably want to show a nice "you've been authorized" page or something
```

And then the handler.onmessage callback will be called and you can do whatever you need to do now that the user's verified their email address.

Hope that helps a bit!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question. You say that I should request a token with HMLHttpRequest. How is this done? I am still studying the documentation, and my understanding is that the app (not the client) needs to open the channel. Can you give more clues about the order? For instance, if the client id=12345; I assume that `channel.create_channel(12345)` will open the channel. Is this correct? Thanks again.

Comment: I asked a new question specifically about Channel API if you want to look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942814/how-can-i-use-google-app-engine-python-channel-api-with-chrome-extension Thanks.

Comment: Added lots more detail above; I think it obviates the need for the other question.

Comment: Many thanks for detailed explanations. I can now send the email to the user with `/authsender` and when I click on the link in the email I see that `/authhandler` sends the `user_email` to `options.html` (I checked in logging.info) but the `handler.onmessage` in `options.html` is not triggered. The log that I have inside the `function (evt)` in `options.html` is not logged. What am I doing wrong? I updated the question with the code that I have. (I closed the other question as suggested) Thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: I think I am having a javascript problem with reading the returned message so I asked another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960751/how-to-use-onmessage-inside-addeventlistener. Any suggestions about what I am doing wrong? Thanks.