# How to get a url parameter in background.html (Chrome extension)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

As a follow up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939633/how-can-i-send-email-to-chrome-extension), if a user clicks to a link I sent him in an email like this

```
<a href="chrome-extension://obilma.../background.html?userEmail=confirmed">click here to confirm your email</a>
```

is there a way I can get the url parameter `userEmail=confirmed` in `background.html`?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if you can open the background page separately. You'd better send data to the background page in some other way.

Comment: @pimvdb, so the above won't work then? What other way I can send the information from the app to the background.html. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Is that link placed with a content script? If so, you can communicate with `sendRequest`: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html.

Comment: No, I am using a google app engine backend and that will send the email. Initially, `options.html` sends the variable "newUser" to the app. I have more information in my previous question if you want to look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939633/how-can-i-send-email-to-chrome-extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
var query = window.location.toString().substring(window.location.toString().indexOf('=')+1);
alert(query);
```