# How to use onMessage inside addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

I save the value of a `textarea id="save"` inside `addEventListener`. Then, I send it to the server with `xhr` and at the same time I open a channel by using Google App Engine Channel API, then I am trying to capture the message sent back with `onMessage`.

Everything works, except the returned message. I understand that the returned message will be `evt.data` but it is not logged. Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong? This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939633/how-can-i-send-data-to-chrome-extension). Thanks!

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener
(
    "click", 
    function ()
    {
        var userEmail = document.getElementById("getEmail").value;
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("extension_user", userEmail);

        var channel;
        var socket;
        var handler = 
        {
            //I changed this to "onmessage" as draevor's answer but 
            //I still don't see "evt.data" logged
            onMessage: function (evt)
            {
                //evt.data will be what the server sends in channel.send_message
                console.log("evt.data received from authhandler: " + evt.data);
                alert("evt.data is: " + evt.data)
            }
        };    

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onReadyStateChange = function()
        {   
            //this alert does not trigger
            alert("xhr.onReadyStateChange")
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            {
                token = xhr.responseText;
                //this alert does not trigger
                alert("token: " + token)
                channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
                socket = channel.open(handler);
            }
        };
        xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/authsender", true);
        xhr.send(formData);
        console.log("formData sent to authsender: " + formData);

    }, false
)
```

**UPDATE**

Update as suggested by [draevor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960751/how-to-use-onmessage-inside-addeventlistener/7960918#7960918) I added other properties of `onmessage`. I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522181/gae-channel-api-connection-doesnt-open-on-android-browser) although I am not sure why he puts the properties in single quotes.

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener
(
    "click", 
    function ()
    {
        var userEmail = document.getElementById("getEmail").value;
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("extension_user", userEmail);

        var channel;
        var socket;
        var handler = 
        {
            onopen: onOpen,
            onmessage: onMessage,
            onerror: onError,
            onclose: onClose
        };    

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onReadyStateChange = function()
        {
            //this alert does not trigger
            alert("xhr.onReadyStateChange")
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            {
                token = xhr.responseText;
                //this alert does not trigger
                alert("token: " + token)
                channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
                socket = channel.open(handler);
            }
        };
        xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/authsender", true);
        xhr.send(formData);
        console.log("formData sent to authsender: " + formData);
    }, false
)
onMessage = 
function (evt)
{
    //evt.data will be what the server sends in channel.send_message
    console.log("evt.data received from authhandler: " + evt.data);
    alert("evt.data is: " + evt.data)
}

onOpen =
function ()
{
    alert("onOpen")
}

onError =
function ()
{
    alert("onError")
}

onClose =
function ()
{
    alert("onClose")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is simply having named the property `onMessage` instead of `onmessage`. I would also suggest setting all the other properties (`onopen`, `onerror`, `onclose`), at least for debugging purposes in case the above doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But originally it was `onmessage` and it was still not working; I did some research and I thought it needed to be `onMessage` and I changed it. So, I will put it back to `onmessage`. What else can I try?

Comment: is the function at least called? I mean, is the alert getting triggered? If not, try setting the other properties, as I said and see if they are called.

Comment: I don't think the function is called, alert is not triggered. I updated the question with other properties, still I don't see the alert.

Comment: Then you'll just have to do more debugging - put an alert where you receive the token (to see if the xhr call actually succeeds) and look at the token itself, maybe it's wrong.

Comment: ok, I added 2 new alerts, xhr call does not seem to succeed, alerts are not triggered. Did I put them in the right place? How can fix that xhr succeeds?

Comment: The only error I see is that you've named it `onReadyStateChange` instead of `onreadystatechange`. Besides that, not really sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing to lower case now the alert for the token triggers but I am still having problems because Chrome fails to load the channel `jsapi`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961638/why-does-google-app-engine-channel-api-jsapi-fail-to-load-in-chrome Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

window.onmessage is used for sending messages between frames. The Channel API uses this. So if you create your own window.onmessage -- which you're doing here -- all heck breaks loose.

Just define your handlers inline, or call them something else entirely (handleChannelMessage or what-have-you).

Comment: Sorry, I went back to your original answer and tried again and now the alert right under the token definition is triggered and I see the token id but then I get the jsapi failure. Thanks again.