# Why does Google App Engine Channel API (jsapi) fail to load in a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using the Channel API in a Chrome extension.

In [Google App Engine Channel API Javascript Reference (Python)](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/javascript.html) page it says that

> Include the following in your html page before any JavaScript code
>   that refers to it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
```

So, I put that in the header of my options.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Extension Options</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
</head>
```

but Chrome throws `jsapiFailed to load resource` error. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

As per Moishe's answer I updated the call to jsapi like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Extension Options</title>
    <!-- this does not work because it is local
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Update**

I added `onopen` and other properties. Now I get the `onopen` alert but I am not getting the `evt.data` alert. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Extension Options</title>
    <!-- this does not work because it is local url
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Enter your gmail address:</p>

<textarea id="getEmail" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 250px; height: 20px">
</textarea><br />

<button id="save">Save</button>
<!--<button id="save">Clear</button>-->

<script>
document.getElementById("getEmail").placeholder = "your gmail address" ;

//save entered gmail address
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener
(
    "click", 
    function ()
    {
        var userEmail = document.getElementById("getEmail").value;
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("extension_user", userEmail);
        alert("after formData.append")

        var channel;
        var socket;
        var handler = 
        {
            onopen: function () { alert("onopen") },
            onerror: function () { alert("onerror") },
            onclose: function () { alert("onclose") },
            onmessage: 
            function (evt)
            {
                //evt.data will be what the server sends in channel.send_message
                console.log("evt.data received from authhandler: " + evt.data);
                alert("evt.data is: " + evt.data)
            }
        };    

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //changed to lowercase
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            //alert("xhr.onReadyStateChange")
            //error handling etc not included
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            {
                token = xhr.responseText;
                alert("token: " + token)
                channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
                socket = channel.open(handler);
            }
        };
        xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/authsender", true);
        xhr.send(formData);
        console.log("formData sent to authsender: " + formData);
    }, false
)



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this using the dev_appserver or in production? Can you provide any details for the "Network" tab in Chrome dev tools?

Comment: This is in production. First there was nothing in "Network" tab; then I reloaded the page as instructed and I see 2 items: options.html and jsapi: name: options.html; Method: GET; Status:(from cache); Type:text/html; Size:(from cache); Time:3ms and `jsapi /_ah/channel; GET, (failed); undefined; 30B; 5ms` Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind telling me your appid? What happens if you try to navigate directly to "http://your-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/channel/jsapi"?

Comment: sure it is ting-1, so when I paste the above with app id it redirects to https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js with bunch of code on the page

Comment: If it works directly from the browser, what's different about your app's "options.html" request for /_ah/channel/jsapi? Is options.html hosted on ting-1.appspot.com? (when I tried to load it I got a 404)

Comment: No, options.html is the Chrome extension. It has a url like `chrome://extensions/` but I don't think it is possible to open it directly on the browser (there is no url shown on the browser when the page is open). I open it as a new tab from the background page of the extension and I take the email of the user and send it to the app, as I was asking in my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a chrome extension, you'll need to directly specify the path for the Channel javascript (https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js). The request for /_ah/channel/jsapi can't be redirected by anything because the file that's trying to load it is local.

Comment: Sorry, about the title I should have mentioned "Chrome extension." Now I don't get the original error but I am getting another one and I am not sure if it is related to my code:

`Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onopen' of object [object Object] is not a function` on line 77 of channel.js.

Is this related to a problem with my `function (evt)`? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant but network tab shows GET 200-OK for `bind
235.talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/dch`

Comment: You need to specify an onopen callback in your handler.

Comment: Thanks. I added onopen and other properties and I see the alert for onopen but I don't see the alert for the message. I updated the question with the latest code. What am I missing? Thanks again.

Comment: Make sure you're calling send_message using the same client id that you used to create the token. Some logging on the server side will help with this.

Comment: I uploaded the app again and it started to work. So now it all works. Thanks for all your help with this. I will update my original question.