# Chrome Extension - Channels Not Working

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension, channel

I am trying to create a channel to my Google App Engine (Python) server, and there seems to be a problem but I am unsure why. When the user toggles the extension, it authenticates the user. If successful, the server replies with a channel token which I use to create the channel. When I authenticate the user, `alert("a")` appears, but `alert("b")` does not which makes me believe there is a problem with the line `var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(msg.token);`, but the console does not report an error.

I have also copied the javascript code from [here](https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js) and placed it in my manifest as oppose to putting `<script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>` in background.html.

```
//script.js
function authenticate(callback) {
    var url = "https://r-notes.appspot.com/init/api/authenticate.json?username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    $.post(url, function(data) {
        if (data.status == "200") {
            channelToken = data.channeltoken;
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
            var port = chrome.extension.connect({name: "myChannel"});
            port.postMessage({token: channelToken});
            port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
                console.log(msg.question);
            });         
        }
    }); 
}


//background.html
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        alert("a"); //pops up
        var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(msg.token);
        alert("b"); //does not pop up
        console.log(channel); //display error ' Error in event handler for 'undefined': ReferenceError: goog is not defined '
        var socket = channel.open()
        socket.onopen = function() {
          // Do stuff right after opening a channel
          console.log('socket opened');
        }
        socket.onmessage = function(evt) {
          // Do more cool stuff when a channel message comes in
          console.log('message recieved');
          console.log(evt);
        }
    });
}); 


//manifest.json
{
    "name": "moot",
    "description": "Clicking on the moot button will display a sidebar!",
    "version": "0.2.69",
    "background_page": "html/background.html",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/icon_64.png",
        "default_title": "moot"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["js/channelApi.js", 
                   "js/script.js", "js/mootsOnSidebar.js", "js/mootsOnPage.js", "js/authenticate.js", "js/otherFunctions.js",
                   "js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js", "js/jquery/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js", "js/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js", 
                   "js/jquery/jquery.autosize.js", "js/jquery/jquery.mousewheel.min.js", "js/jquery/jquery.easing.1.3.js",
                   "js/channel.js"],
            "css": ["css/cssReset.css", "css/sidebar.css", "css/onPageCreate.css", "css/onPageExists.css", "css/scrollbar.css", "css/authenticate.css"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "contextMenus", "http://*/*", "https://*/"
    ],
    "icons": {
      "16": "img/icon_16.png",
      "64": "img/icon_64.png"
    }
}
```

EDIT - After doing `console.log(channel)`, I discovered the error ' Error in event handler for 'undefined': ReferenceError: goog is not defined '. I am unsure why I receive this error as I did include the required javascript file as I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961638/why-does-google-app-engine-channel-api-jsapi-fail-to-load-in-a-chrome-extensio).

Comment: Can you show your manifest file? Did you request the right permissions? Open the background page (a Dev tools instance), via the `chrome://extensions/` > Developer mode, and check for any errors (also, any `console.log` calls inside the background page will be visible at this Dev tools page).

Comment: Sweet trick! I had no idea that you can check the background page for console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is that you need to include the file `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js"></script>` in a HTML page. I placed this on the first row of background.html.

My mistake was saving a local copy of channel.js, and refer to it in manifest.json.

I'm now going to place a copy of channel.js on my server, and refer to my server's copy. I don't think there will be any issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

Make a console log for the value of msg direct between alert("a") and var channel = ...
and inspect the value.

Comment: I just added `console.log(msg)` right after `alert("a")` but the console did not report anything. I went back to authenticate.js and double checked that `console.log(channelToken)` did exist. I copied the message passing code off Google's API.

Comment: Wait. I just realized... if you `console.log()` inside background.html, would the reply actually show up in the console? From my understanding, it should not which is why I subconsciously used `alerts()`.

Comment: I instead did `alert(msg.token)` and I did get a prompt with my token.